# Complex "Order By" using Specification API Hibernate

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, kotlin

Is there any way i can do this select query using Hibernate Specification API (criteria API)?

```
select * from employee order by (CASE
                                     WHEN full_name IS NOT NULL
                                         AND  full_name <> '' THEN full_name
                                     WHEN CONCAT(first_name, last_name) IS NOT NULL
                                         AND  CONCAT(first_name, last_name) <> '' THEN CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name)
    END) nulls first
```

My specification method:

```
 Specification { root: Root<Employee>, criteriaQuery: CriteriaQuery<*>, cb: CriteriaBuilder ->
...

criteriaQuery.orderBy(
                    cb.asc(
                        //TODO something?
                    )
                )
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Route> query = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Employee.class);

List<Order> orders = new ArrayList();

Root<Employee> employeeRoot = query.from(Employee.class);
orders.add(criteriaBuilder.desc(employeeRoot .get("firstName")));
orders.add(criteriaBuilder.desc(employeeRoot .get("lastName")));
query.orderBy(orders);
```